# How to combine the results of two different queries into a single query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a query that displays the total amount of matches won by individual teams in the database,

```sql
select t.name, count(*) 'Matches_Won' 
from test.team t 
inner join test.match_scores m on m.winner = t.id 
group by t.name 
order by Matches_Won desc;
```

Another query prints out the total number of Matches Played by the Individual Teams in the database,

```sql
select t.name, count(*) 'Matches_PLayed' from test.team t inner join test.results r on r.home_team = t.id or r.away_team = t.id group by t.name
order by Matches_Played desc;
```

Now, I am trying to combine these two queries, I want a table with three columns,

1. Team Name
2. Matches Played
3. Matches Won

I tried to **union** the two queries, but it didn't work. Anyone who can guide me on this?

This is the **Team Table**

[image]

This is the **Match Scores Table**. In this table, the columns "Home Team", "Away Team" represents the Goals scored by respective team and the "Winner" is the foreign key, referring to the Team Table.

[image]

This is the **Results Table**, where `home_team` and `away_team` are `foreign keys referring to the Teams Table`.

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union unions two result sets. You want to have both results, something like a merged.

The following statement isn't proved, but it should show you the idea of the solution. You have to join both, the results and the played games in one query.

```
select t.name, count(distinct m.id) 'Matches_Won', count(distinct r.id) 'Matches_PLayed' 
from test.team t 
left join test.match_scores m on m.winner = t.id 
left join test.results r on r.home_team = t.id or r.away_team = t.id
group by t.name 
order by Matches_Won, Matches_Played desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

can you join them based on team_name instead of union?

```
select 
matchesplayed.name ,Matches_Won,Matches_PLayed
from 
(
select t.name, count(*) 'Matches_PLayed' from test.team t inner join test.results r on r.home_team = t.id or r.away_team = t.id group by t.name
) matchesplayed
LEFT JOIN (select t.name, count(*) 'Matches_Won' 
from test.team t 
inner join test.match_scores m on m.winner = t.id 
group by t.name  ) matchesown
ON matchesown.name = matchesplayed.name
order by 1
```

Now, if a team looses all the matches, they will also show up with null  in matches won column(left join is used for that).